# Showing/Hiding Div based on Data Attribute

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hide elements that have specific data attributes but having issues doing so. In this case, I am trying to trying to hide deals or coupons based on the button user clicks. Also trying to show everything based on show all.

Can someone please help with what I am doing wrong.

Code here

```js
function showdeals(dealtype) {
  if (dealtype == "all") {
   $('div[data-deal-type="deal"]').show();
   $('div[data-deal-type="coupon"]').show();

  }
  if (dealtype == "deal") {
   $('div[data-deal-type="deal"]').hide();
   $('div[data-deal-type="coupon"]').show();
  }
  else if (dealtype == "coupon") {
   $('div[data-deal-type="deal"]').show();
   $('div[data-deal-type="coupon"]').hide();
  }
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="showdeals('all')">
Show All 
</button>
<button onclick="showdeals('deal')">
Show Deals
</button>
<button onclick="showdeals('coupon')">
Show coupons 
</button>




<div id="536739" class="coupon-modal" data-deal-type="coupon" data-discount-type="data-coupon-rank=" xxx=""> Coupon1 </div>

<div id="536738" class="coupon-modal" data-deal-type="coupon" data-discount-type="data-coupon-rank=" xxx=""> coupon2 </div>

<div id="536737" class="coupon-modal" data-deal-type="deal" data-discount-type="data-coupon-rank=" xxx=""> Deal1 </div>

<div id="536736" class="coupon-modal" data-deal-type="deal" data-discount-type="data-coupon-rank=" xxx=""> deal2 </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try running your snippet. (Really, really need to test them before you post your question.)

Comment: I fixed it for you.

Comment: Voting to close as typo/unreproducible. It's just the condition is backward.

Answer (score 1):

You just have your conditions backward. You're hiding deals when you're supposed to show them, and vice-versa, and the same for coupons.

```
if (dealtype == "all") {
    $('div[data-deal-type="deal"]').show();
    $('div[data-deal-type="coupon"]').show();
}
if (dealtype == "deal") {
    $('div[data-deal-type="deal"]').hide();       // Should show
    $('div[data-deal-type="coupon"]').show();     // Should hide
}
else if (dealtype == "coupon") {
    $('div[data-deal-type="deal"]').show();       // Should hide
    $('div[data-deal-type="coupon"]').hide();     // Should show
}
```

(You could use another `else` although it doesn't really matter.)

That said, you can do it more simply:

```
function showdeals(dealtype) {
  $('div[data-deal-type="deal"]').toggle(
    dealtype == "all" || dealtype == "deal"
  );
  $('div[data-deal-type="coupon"]').toggle(
    dealtype == "all" || dealtype == "coupon"
  );
}
```

```js
function showdeals(dealtype) {
  $('div[data-deal-type="deal"]').toggle(
    dealtype == "all" || dealtype == "deal"
  );
  $('div[data-deal-type="coupon"]').toggle(
    dealtype == "all" || dealtype == "coupon"
  );
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showdeals('all')">
  Show All
</button>
<button onclick="showdeals('deal')">
  Show Deals
</button>
<button onclick="showdeals('coupon')">
  Show coupons
</button>




<div id="536739" class="coupon-modal" data-deal-type="coupon" data-discount-type="data-coupon-rank=" xxx="">Coupon1</div>

<div id="536738" class="coupon-modal" data-deal-type="coupon" data-discount-type="data-coupon-rank=" xxx="">coupon2</div>

<div id="536737" class="coupon-modal" data-deal-type="deal" data-discount-type="data-coupon-rank=" xxx="">Deal1</div>

<div id="536736" class="coupon-modal" data-deal-type="deal" data-discount-type="data-coupon-rank=" xxx="">deal2</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```